# How fast can a cockroach scaled up to 1:72 scale(72 times bigger) run and move barring the square-cube law?

Tags: apocalypse, insects, mutants

I had a passing idea for a world where giant cockroaches attack a city and was wondering how fast can they run at this scale. I know that even normal-sized cockroaches are fast, so must be even more so bigger. So how fast can a cockroach 72 times bigger, especially of the pest variety like German and American cockroaches, run, fly, and move with out taking that pesky square-cube law into consideration    ?

Comment: Ignoring square-cube law conflicts with the "science-based" tag.

Comment: Fixed!@ZeissIkon

Comment: doesnt their speed directly connect to the square-cube law? their legs are so small compared to the rest of their body that they probably wont be any faster when scaled up

Comment: Ignoring weight, how much do you weigh? .. You *cannot* tell us to ignore a law of nature, and **Then** ask us how that very same law of nature scales up.

Comment: What does "with out taking that pesky square-cube law into consideration" even *mean*? You're basically asking a physics question and saying "ignore physics". On what basis are we supposed to answer?

Comment: I mean like do not say " The square-cube law makes this impossible, it can not move!!!",or "It is to large to breath since the spiracles system does not work at that size!!!". I am not saying do not tell me how it weights up or what ever. @PcMan

Comment: You might consider rephrasing your question to be something like: "Given an Earth-like world were Giganticus Handwavius applied to cockroaches has created monstrosities 72x larger than normal, what is the average velocity of these behemoths?" This makes it clear you're aware these creatures would normally not survive, but you want a science-focused answer.

Comment: You ask us to calculate how fast it can move and fly, but you want us to disregard physics, chemistry and biology? Sure: your roach can run at the speed of light and fly at Mach 55. If you just want oversized roaches that ignore the laws of our universe (which dictate how fast something can move and other stuff) you could either just Google their speed and multiply it by 72 or just have them run at whatever speeds you need them to enable them to evade the military and destroy a city.

Comment: when you double the size of the roach's leg, you increase the mass by 8(2 to the power of 3) folds but the cross sectional area of the leg by only 4(2 to the power of 2) times so it will have much difficulty supporting itself up let alone move and that's square-cube law! so now imagine scaling it up 72x!!! It will certainly collapse under its own weight but at least it don't have to turn turtle ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cockroach can grow upto 2 inches, the [American one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_cockroach#Biology) upto 1.6 inches long and 0.28 inches tall.

Since you are ignoring the square cube law, its hard to imagine such an entity, so at 72X, lets ignore the volume/weight increase for a moment.

Your SuperCokroach will have a length of ~300 cm / 9.6ft  and height of ~ 50 cm/1.68ft. Those are the dimensions of an [average female saltwater crocodile](https://www.dimensions.com/element/saltwater-crocodile).

A cockroach can have inch long tentacles, so your super cockroach will have 6 feet of tentacles, which can impact movement speed negatively by getting in the way, more probe area to be covered etc.

Another animal to look for would be a fully grown [male Komodo dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon) with maximum length of 10 feet.

A realistic estimate would thus be to model the  Super Cockroach as a reptile and use a speed of [13-20 kmph](https://www.dimensions.com/element/saltwater-crocodile) on land (Komodos manage 20km/hour, crocs around 13-17km/hour on land). Depending on the type of legs you provide to your super cockroach (can't scale the legs as is because  weight and weight distribution is different), you may be able to increase the speed by a small multiplier at best from that.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the cockroach uses proportionally the same stride and keeps the cadence it had, it should move 72 times as fast as its tiny household pest cousins; those critters can run at well over a meter per second, which would put your Super Cockroaches at 72+ m/s (or close to 150 miles per hour, if you think in those units).

That's unlikely to be the case, however, even ignoring square-cube law; larger animals tend to "live slower" than smaller ones.  This is why dogs live longer than rats, and horses longer than dogs (though when you jump from mammals to birds or reptiles, you have to start over with size comparisons).  If we take that into account, however, your dino-roaches are still going to be plenty fast -- say, capable of freeway speeds...